# How can I remove the element highlighting when visiting a section in the same page?

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #64bef7;  
}
```

[Blue highlight around elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnoGL.png)

The blue rectangle disappears when clicked outside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzMph.jpg)

Comment: use hover in css

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS;

```
* { outine:none; }
```

Since * denotes universal element, it reset all outlines for elements default and for all events

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the outline property. 
`outline: none` before the hover action.

Comment: Thank you so much.